# What is the limit of $\lim_{x\to\infty} \sin^2{(\frac{1}{n^{48}})}((n+\frac{1}{n^3})^{100}-(n^{32}+n^{10}+1)^3-n^{100})$

Tags: calculus, limits

Hi I have problem to evaluate this limit:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \sin^2{(\frac{1}{n^{48}})}((n+\frac{1}{n^3})^{100}-(n^{32}+n^{10}+1)^3-n^{100}).$$

I tried to use the binomial theorem and tried to subtract the n  with power hundred, but I am really struggling.

I can get to something like:

$\lim_{x\to\infty} \sin^2{(\dfrac{1}{n^{48}})}(n^{100}+\sum_{i=0}^{99}\binom{99}{i}n^{99-j}(\dfrac{1}{n^3})^j - (n^{42}+1)^3 -n^{100})$

$\lim_{x\to\infty} \sin^2{(\dfrac{1}{n^{48}})}(\sum_{i=0}^{99}\binom{99}{i}n^{99-j}(\dfrac{1}{n^3})^j - (n^{42}+1)^3)$

and from here I am stucky really, I am not even sure if these steps before were somewhat helpful.

Comment: You cannot add $n^{32}$ and $n^{10}$ to get $n^{42}$

Comment: Everywhere you have $x$ it should be $n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint. Note that you need just a small part of the two expansions:
$$\left(n+\dfrac{1}{n^3}\right)^{100}=n^{100}+100n^{96}+o(n^{96}),$$
and
$$(n^{32}+n^{10}+1)^3=n^{96}+ o(n^{96}).$$
Can you take it from here?

P.S. The binomial coefficient in your first expansion should be $\binom{100}{i}$.

Answer (score 0):

Since by Taylor expansion for $n \rightarrow \infty, \sin\left( \frac{1}{n^{48}} \right) \approx \frac{1}{n^{48}}$, a good idea is to consider only the terms of degree greater than or equal to 96, since the others goes to 0. Hence the limit shall be 
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sin^2 \left( \frac{1}{n^{48}}\right)\left ( \left ( n + \frac{1}{n^3} \right)^{100} - \left( n^{32} + n^{10} +1 \right)^3 - n^{100} \right) = \\
= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n^{96}} \left( n^{100} + {{100}\choose{1}} n^{96} - n^{96} - n^{100}\right) = {{100}\choose{1}} - 1  $$